# Prevent drawing lines on black portion of an imageview

Tags: android, canvas, view, imageview, paint

[image]

While drawing a line or circle using paint i can able to draw on the black portion of the imageview.The image is a custom imageview with zoom that extending to AppCompactImageView.And for drawing ,we use a Custom view that extends View and lines are drawing using paint in a canvas

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a clipping region, and then you will only be able to draw inside that clipping region.

```
canvas?.clipRect(100,200,600,800)
```

where 100,200,600 and 800 are coordinates for left, top, right and bottom of you clipping region.

Sample Output:

[image: Sample Output]